# Навигация в UWP (Кнопка назад)

Tags: c#, uwp, mobile-development, windows-10-mobile, навигация

пишу приложение для телефона на Windows 10
В приложение использую гамбургер меню , по этому стандартную навигация через `Frame` реализовать не удалась, так как это тупой переход на новую страницу, а при использование гамбургер меню нужно вставлять страницу в `<SplitView.Content>`
Написал свой класс для навигации, в режиме десктопа вся навигация работает отлично, но вот когда начал тестировать на телефоне и в режиме плашета , системная кнопка назад работает не так как хотелось, когда нажимаешь на системную кнопку назад , предыдущая страница возвращается но приложение сворачивается ... Помогите как ее обмануть? может можно както заполнить `Frame` не переходя по страницам ?
P.S.
`destPage` - это перемена с именем страницы , например `typeof (Enter)`;
`HamburgerMenu` - это имя `<SplitView>`;
`App.NavigationHistory` - это `Stack<Type>` для записи переходов
Пример моего кода навигации если нужно:

```
 internal class AppNavigation
    {
        internal static void SetBackButtonVisibility()
        {
            if (App.NavigationHistory.Count > 0)
            {
                SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility =
                    AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility =
                    AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }

    internal static void SetSplitViewContent(SplitView HamburgerMenu, Type destPage, bool push)
    {
        if (push)
        {
            var type = HamburgerMenu.Content?.GetType();
            if (destPage != type)
            {                               
                AddToBackStack(type);
                HamburgerMenu.Content = (UserControl)Activator.CreateInstance(destPage);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            HamburgerMenu.Content = (UserControl)Activator.CreateInstance(RemoveFromBackStack());
        }
    }

    internal static void AddToBackStack(Type type)
    {
        App.NavigationHistory.Push(type);
        SetBackButtonVisibility();
    }

    internal static Type RemoveFromBackStack()
    {
        var type = App.NavigationHistory.Pop();
        SetBackButtonVisibility();
        return type;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Добавил вот такую реакцию на нажатие кнопки назад в главную страницу приложения App.xaml.cs

```
   protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
            { SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += App_BackRequested;}

 private void App_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!e.Handled)
            {
                var mainPage = (Window.Current.Content as Frame)?.Content as MainPage;
                var HamburgerMenu = mainPage?.FindName("HamburgerMenu") as SplitView;
                AppNavigation.SetSplitViewContent(HamburgerMenu, null, false);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```